# Minimum of a sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I have the function $$f(x)= \sum_{i=1}^n (x-a_i)^2 \ x\in R$$ I am asked to find the minimum of it. I am lost so any help would be nice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you already know how to differentiate?

Comment: yes i know how to

Comment: Good. How can differentiating $f$ help you find the minimum?

Comment: Sure, I end up with f'(x)= 2*(n*x - (a1+a2+...+an)). Then what?

Comment: How is $f'$ related to minima (and maxima) of $f$?

Comment: Dude,no offence but I know math. I am in uni. I just need some help cause I am kinda lost here. Would the answer be the average? I mean f'(x) = 0 for x = (a1+a2+...+an)/n ?

Comment: Okay, so $f$ has a unique critical point at the mean of the $a_i$. Since $f$ is a sum of squares, it is clear that $f$ has its unique minimum there. Case closed.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=(x-a)^2+(x-2a)^2+..+(x-na)^2\\
f(x)&=x^2+a^2-2ax+x^2+4a^2-4ax...+x^2+n^2a^2-2nxa
\end{align}$$

Now group the $x^2$ terms together,x terms together and the constants together.

Comment: Sure, but suppose what the OP really wants to say is: $f(x)= \sum_{i=1}^n (x-a_i)^2 \quad ; \quad x\in \mathbb{R}$